# React Native Compass using Expo

Tags: react-native

I want to display compass on my react-native project, i use this [compas-github](https://github.com/remigallego/react-native-compass) i already follow all step on that link but got error like this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSZI5.jpg).
I really new to this.
Please help me or suggest another way to display compass on react-native.
Big thanks

This is my code

> import React, {Component} from "react";
>       import { Text,View, StyleSheet, Image, Animated, Easing, Dimensions} from "react-native";
>       import {Location, Permissions} from 'expo';
>       import {
>         Container,
>         Header,
>         Content,
>       } from "native-base";
>
> ```
> export default class KompasPage extends Component{
>
>       constructor(props) {
>         super(props);
>         this.spinValue = new Animated.Value(0);
>         this.state = {
>           location: null,
>           //errorMessage: null,
>           heading: null,
>           truenoth: null,
>           timer: false,
>         };
>       }
>
>       timePass() {
>         this.setState({ timer: true });
>       }
>
>       componentWillMount() {
>         setTimeout(() => {
>           this.timePass();
>         }, 1000);
>         this._getLocationAsync();
>       }
>
>       componentWillUpdate()
>       {
>         this.spinValue()
>       }
>
>       _getLocationAsync = async () => {
>         //check dev loc permiss
>         let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
>         if (status !== 'granted') {
>           this.setState({
>             errorMessage : 'Permission to access location was denied',
>           });
>         }
>         else {
>           Expo.Location.watchHeadingAsync((obj) => {
>             let heading = obj.magHeading;
>             this.setState({heading: heading})
>           })
>         }
>       };
>
>       spin() {
>         let start = JSON.stringify(this.spinValue);
>         let heading = Math.round(this.state.heading);
>
>         let rot = +start;
>         let rotM = rot % 360;
>
>         if (rotM < 180 && (heading > (rotM +180)))
>         rot -= 360;
>         if (rotM >= 180 && (heading <= (rotM -180)))
>         rot += 360;
>
>         rot += (heading - rotM)
>
>         Animated.timing(
>           this.spinValue,
>           {
>             toValue: rot,
>             duration: 300,
>             easing: Easing.easeInOut
>           }
>         ).start()
>       }
>
>        render() {
>         const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
>
>         let LoadingText = 'Loading...';
>         let display = LoadingText;
>
>         if (this.state.errorMessage)
>           display = this.state.errorMessage;
>
>         const spin = this.spinValue.interpolate({
>           inputRange: [0,360],
>           outputRange: ['-0deg', '-360deg']
>         })
>
>         display = Math.round(JSON.stringify(this.spinValue))
>
>         if(display < 0)
>           display += 360
>         if(display > 360)
>           display -= 360
>
>         return(
>
>           <View style={styles.container}>
>           <Text style={styles.text}>{display+'°'}</Text>
>           <View style={styles.imageContainer} >
>             <Animated.Image resizeMode='contain' source={require("../image/dasar_kompas.png")}
>               style={{
>               width:  deviceWidth  - 10, height: deviceHeight/2 - 10,
>               left: deviceWidth /2 -  (deviceWidth   - 10)/2, top:  deviceHeight /2 - (deviceHeight/2  - 10)/2,
>               transform: [{rotate: spin}],
>             }} />
>           </View>
>           <View style={styles.arrowContainer} >
>             <Image resizeMode='contain' source={require("../image/kompasbaru.png")} style={styles.arrow} />
>           </View>
>         </View>
>   );
>  }
>  }
>
>  const deviceWidth  =  Dimensions.get('window').width
>  const deviceHeight =  Dimensions.get('window').height
>
>  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
>    container: {
>      flex: 1,
>      alignItems: 'center',
>      justifyContent: 'center',
>    },
>    text: {
>      color: '#263544',
>      fontSize: 80,
>      transform: ([{translateY: -(deviceHeight/2 - (deviceHeight/2  - 10)/2) - 50 }])
>    },
>    imageContainer: {
>      ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
>    },
>    arrowContainer: {
>      ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
>    },
>    arrow: {
>      width: deviceWidth/7,
>      height: deviceWidth/7,
>      left: deviceWidth /2 - (deviceWidth/7)/2,
>      top:  deviceHeight /2  - (deviceWidth/7)/2,
>      opacity: 0.9
>    }
>  });
> ```

Comment: Did you follow the instructions given in the error message? Try to remove node modules and reinstall

Comment: ya but still got same error

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the example you’re following uses some sort of locational data that requires internet for showing direction. If your device has built in compass or magnetometer, you should make use of that. That way it would be more efficient. Here are two examples, one using [expo](https://github.com/rahulhaque/compass-react-native) which is much easier to implement but requires, you guessed it expo. And here is [another](https://github.com/rahulhaque/compass-react-native-non-expo) using only react native.

Comment: Rahul, when you're the owner of a package you link to it's always nice to mention it. Nice work though.